# Variable Interpolation vs. Substitution in printf Format String

Tags: shell, printf, shellcheck

[ShellCheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) gives a warning if you put a variable in the `printf(1)` format string.  Why?

Is:

```
printf "$file does not exist\n"
```

inferior in some way to:

```
printf "%s does not exist\n" "$file"
```

Comment: The shellcheck wiki entry for [SC2059](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2059) (the warning that triggers here) covers this.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that existed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because in theory `file` variable can have some formatting character that will fail the `printf`. These examples will make it more clear:

```
file='my'
printf "$file does not exist\n"
my does not exist    

file='m%y'
printf "$file does not exist\n"
-bash: printf: `y': invalid format character
```

**As per recommendedation** it will work fine:

```
printf "%s does not exist\n" "$file"
m%y does not exist
```